# Is there some way I can pass Chart.AppVersion to a subchart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have a chart that uses on a sub chart to create some resources.

I want to pass the parent chart's appVersion to the subchart for labels and stuff.

I tried to use tpl but when it's evaluated it's the appVersion of the subchart:

```
# values.yaml of parent 
parent-chart:
  blah:
    version: "{{ $.Chart.AppVersion }}"
```

In subchart:

```
...
    version: {{ tpl .Values.blah.version . }}
```

Is there any way to do something like this? I wanted to do this without using a global variable as well assuming that is possible.

### Edit

It looks like I might be waiting on this PR? https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/10059

Comment: From my experience it is not possible reach for parent data. It also makes sense when considering that subcharts are supposed to work independently.

Comment: for now the only way is to move it to `global` in the `Values` ,  even though accessing it is quite ugly

Comment: Even using globals is impossible. You cant reassign the "{{ $.Chart.AppVersion }}" of the parent to a new global. its always going to be the subchart value that is returned.